# Testing Condition on File permission

Tags: linux, unix, shell

i am learning shell scriptnig,
is there any way i can test the operation like checking file permission on a file..
like...
i know some of the way like. searching the file through find command using permission,
or in "ls...| grep 'r--r--r' smthg.. whatever permission u wan't

I have some file how i check whether the file have the required permission or not..?\

Thanks in advance..

Comment: don't count on parsing the output of `ls`. What if there is a file called `-r--r--r--`? :)

Comment: that was just example...but if you realy want to do then .
using awk commadnd u can check on the required field only like on permission column

Comment: ok, but what if one of the filenames has an embedded newline?

Comment: Did you text this question from your phone?

Comment: @genibbler: ya seems i am wrong..  i was just completing my task.but that's not the correct way...how to do in this cases...
can u suggest...?
@Dennis : no from my PC...? why..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like:

Test for execution:

```
if [ -x "$file" ]; then
  #do_something
fi
```

Test for writing:

```
if [ -w "$file" ]; then
  #do_something
fi
```

Test for reading:

```
if [ -r "$file" ]; then
  #do_something
fi
```

Comment: Can I used it this way  if [ -r -w "$file"] ?

Answer (score 2):

```
stat FILENAME --print=%A
```

see `man stat` for more options - you can check the group/owner/etc.

Comment: thanks this is what i was required.. but don't know what is happenning on my unix server it is hanging ..& not giving anykind of output. 
thanks any way.. i wil try it on some other machine..

Comment: This should be the selected answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [test](http://www.nsc.ru/cgi-bin/www/unix_help/unix-man?test+1)

The options -r -x -w test for read,execute and write permission.
In a shell script the test command is usually entered as [

Answer (score 0):

Check the [man page of find.](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find) under EXAMPLES. you can see how to find files with desired permission.